# Delphi: Maths expression

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is it possible to type a maths sum into an edit box and for a label to produce an answer?
example if I type (3*4)*2 how can I get the edit box to read (3*4)*2 as an expression?

Thanks

Kerisha

Answer (score 8):

Yes is possible, but using an additional component, I will recommend you `TEvaluator` which is part of the [`JCL (Jedi Code library)`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library).

Check this very simple example (just put a EditText with the expression to evaluate)

```
uses
  JclExprEval;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Eval : TEvaluator;
begin
  Eval := TEvaluator.Create;
  try
    ShowMessage(Format('The result is %g', [Eval.Evaluate(Edit1.Text)]));
  finally
    Eval.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, there are quite a few simple and some not-so-simple expression evaluators for Delphi. Most of these are free and freely available. But the JCL one is a good recommendation.